# Inject different implementations of the same interface using micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Lets say I have `MotoDao` and `CarDao`, and both are implementations of the interface `VehicleDao`.

How to inject both to a class using micronuat?

I expect sth like below:

```java
@Inject
public VehicleHandler(@MotoDao VehcileDao motoDao, @CarDao VehicleDao carDao)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@Named` annotation to qualify by the prefix (*moto*, *car*) like this:

```java
@Inject
public VehicleHandler(@Named('moto') VehcileDao motoDao, @Named('car') VehicleDao carDao)
```

Or you can create your own qualifier annotations:

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Car {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface Moto {
}
```

Annotate your DAO classes by them:

```java
@Moto
public class MotoDao implements VehicleDao {
    ...
}
```

... and and use it like this:

```java
@Inject
public VehicleHandler(@Moto VehcileDao motoDao, @Car VehicleDao carDao)
```

You can find more datail in the official Micronaut documentation here: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/ioc.html

Comment: Thanks for providing the document and I really cannot find it. It works the same as using guice!